# HOw to send an email from PHPmyadmin DB using the Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to send mail using stored procedure using the My SQL in the PHPmyadmin

regards,
hemant

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.
But if you really want to send e-mail from mysql,
you can compile [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-udf.html)